# Clonar base MongoDB para usar en otra computadora

Tags: mongodb

Tengo una base de datos con varias colecciones y documentos en MongoDB, esta base es local y de prueba, lo que quiero es poder "clonarla" para poder utilizarla en otra computadora.

Por ejemplo, tengo la base "Cafe", con la colección "Gustos" y dentro de "Gustos" un documento:

```
{
   "nombre": "prueba",
   "estado": 1
}
```

Se que podría seedear la base desde codigo, el tema es que en esta base ya tengo muchos datos y no quiero ponerme a escribir todos los objetos en js para poder insertarlos desde el codigo, quiero poder exportar lo que ya tengo para importarlo directamente si es que se puede.
Como haría para exportar estos datos y poder importarlos en otra computadora que tengo para seguir programando desde esa otra computadora?

Answer (score 1):

Si, estas usando la herramienta `MongoDB Compass`, puedes exportar las colecciones que necesites.

Lo único que debes hacer, es entrar a tu DB, luego a tu colección y buscar la opción `Export Collection`.

[image: Interfaz Export Collection]

Luego veras una cuadro de dialogo en la que puedes definir los filtros de exportación o seleccionar exportar la colección completa.

Esto generará un archivo json, que también puedes importar a la base de tu otra computadora (Opción ADD DATA).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @GFlores98! Ahora mismo no puedo probarlo pero tiene toda la pinta de que me va a servir, apenas lo pruebo si funciona lo marco como respuesta correcta!